# Create transect line in shiny app using a mix of hover and click

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on a shiny app which contains an image, and then lets you draw a transect line on that image.

The current app lets you double click to create a starting point for the transect, and then it will use the mouse hover position to create a 'end' point for the transect. As you move the mouse, the transect updates with the new mouse position.

What I'd like to do is be able to double click again, and this would 'confirm' the end point of the transect, so the transect would now be fixed in place, and would not respond to mouse hover. Is there someway I can do this?

```
library(shiny)
library(magick)
library(ggplot2)


create_image <- function(loaded_image, image_data) {

  displayed_image <- loaded_image +
    geom_point(data = image_data, aes(x = .data$x_values,
                                      y = .data$y_values)) +
    geom_path(data = image_data, aes(x = .data$x_values,
                                     y = .data$y_values
    ),
    color = "black")
  return(displayed_image)
}



ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel(""),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("current_image_plot", dblclick = "double_click", hover = "hover")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  image_data <- shiny::reactiveValues()
  image_data$double_click <- data.frame(x_values=c(NA_real_,NA_real_), y_values = c(NA_real_,NA_real_))

  loaded_image <- magick::image_ggplot(image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png"))

  output$current_image_plot <- renderPlot({
    displayed_image <- create_image(loaded_image,
                                    image_data$double_click
    )
    return(displayed_image)
  })

  observeEvent({input$double_click}, {
    clickrow <- data.frame(x_values = input$double_click$x,
                           y_values = input$double_click$y)

    image_data$double_click[1,] <- clickrow

    new_hov<-reactive(
      input$hover
    )  %>% debounce(millis = 150)

    observeEvent(new_hov(), {
      nh <- new_hov()
      hoverrow <- data.frame(x_values = nh$x,
                             y_values = nh$y)

      image_data$double_click[2,] <- hoverrow
    })
  })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy to achieve:

1. Add a new variable `n` in the reactiveValues:

   `image_data <- reactiveValues(n = 1)`
2. Use that variable to index the (x,y) pair on double_click, then increment it:

   `image_data$double_click[image_data$n, ] <- clickrow`

   `image_data$n <- image_data$n + 1`
3. Use it also on the hover event :

   `image_data$double_click[image_data$n, ] <- hoverrow`

This will keep adding more points to the path. If you want no more points, you can disable events when `n` turns 3.

Comment: Great solution mate, thanks very much. Just for posterity, I disabled events for n > 3 by wrapping each of the `image_data$double_click[image_data$n, ] <- clickrow` and `image_data$double_click[image_data$n, ] <- hoverrow` inside `if (image_data$n < 3){}`